# jquery data returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I'm trying to store some data in DOM Elements `($.cache)` on my plugin but I am facing some problem as mentioned below...

`$(_buelement).data('yazi')` returns `undefined` on `metodlar.gizle` but it works on `metodlar.goster` where I store the data.

In my plugin metodlar.goster initiates on onMounseIn and metodlar.gizle onMouseOut.

```
            $.fn.balon = function( metod, girdi ) {
                var _bu = this;
                var metodlar = {
                    goster : function(  ) {

                        return _bu.each(function ( ) {
                            var _buelement = $(this);
                            s.pozisyonAl(_buelement);

                            s.balon.fadeIn(300);
                            $.data(_buelement,{'balon' : s.balon,'yazi':'heyho'});

                        })
                    },
                    gizle : function( ) { 

                        return _bu.each(function ( ) {

                            var _buelement = $(this);

                           $(_buelement).data('yazi');

                        })
                    }
                }


                });
```

Finally I ran some debug and found out the `metodlar.gizle` is just works fine but data is still `undefined`.

Here's Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/4FfWz/4/

Comment: Your code is written in a strange language I cannot begin to understand.

Comment: Yes. That's why I write all my code in English so it doesn't look like gibberish to other people.

Comment: I wouldn't named my native language as gibberish like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the way you store the data in `goster`:

```
_buelement.data({'balon' : s.balon,'yazi':'heyho'});
```

Comment: $.data(_buelement,{'balon' : s.balon,'yazi':'heyho'});
it worked but is this kind of declarations wrong?

Comment: With `$.data(_buelement,{'balon' : s.balon,'yazi':'heyho'});`, `_buelement` is being used as the key to store the data, which makes retrieval problematic because it is a jQuery object.

Comment: @pete That's not quite correct. `$.data` is the low level utility that's used by jQuery and it takes an element as the first argument. However, it doesn't support the "object as key/value pairs" syntax like `element.data()` does.

Comment: The code also had a typo where "method" was used instead of "metod" somewhere.

Comment: Also, here's a slightly cleaned-up version of your fiddle that actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/qJdEs/1/

Comment: Ateş pete'e söylediğini daha rahat anmayabilmem için Türkçe anlatabilir misin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gizle : function( ) { 
   return _bu.each(function ( ) {
          var _buelement = $(this);
          _buelement.data('yazi');
           })
}
```

Comment: @Lupus can you please put your code on jsfiddle and paste that link as part of your question..